# Antonym for "deficient"

Tags: antonyms

What is an appropriate antonym for *deficient*?

> The dissertation is deficient of sources.

It should be a bit more decorated than the phrasing *The dissertation contains enough sources*.

Comment: The phrasing *is deficient of*, is at the very least, [unusual phrasing](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+deficient+of%2Cis+deficient+in&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Letting that pass, the "antonym" would actually have to mean *"has* **too many** *sources"*. But I imagine all you really want to say is something in the range *"is adequately sourced"* through *"is well-sourced"* to ["is exhaustively sourced"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22is+exhaustively+sourced%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thumbs up. Your comment is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say it is **replete** with sources:

> **replete** 
>   *adjective* [ predic. ]
>   filled or well-supplied with something: *sensational popular fiction, replete with adultery and sudden death.*

Answer (score 7):

[*Sufficient*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sufficient), without doubt!

> 1. Equal to the end proposed; adequate to wants; enough; ample; competent; as,
> 2. Possessing adequate talents or accomplishments; of competent power or ability; qualified; fit.

Comment: Hmm. *"The dissertation is sufficient of sources"* doesn't really do it for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sounds about as good as "The dissertation is defficient of sources".

Answer (score 3):

`The dissertation has a surfeit of sources.`

`The dissertation is over-endowed with sources.`

But only if you consider a surplus to be the opposite of a shortage.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to say that there are too much sources. It wasn't clear to me, that this were the *exact* opposite of deficient. But I like your examples.

Answer (score 0):

*Replete* came to my mind as well. *Abundant* is the opposite of *deficient*.

**Edit** to add explanation:

Both the answer choices *replete* and *abundant* are synonymous. *Replete* has already been explained by Robusto who posted the answer choice first.

*Deficient* means lacking in something. The opposite would be having it in excess. Therefore, *abundant* is the opposite of *deficient*.

Answer (score 0):

The dissertation is a cornucopia of resources.